# Virtual ergonomic keyboard for ipad pro?

Tags: ios, keyboard, ipad, ergonomics

Is there a virtual ergononmic keyboard available for the ipad pro?

I am coming from a Windows background and am happy with the physical [Ergonomic Keyboard series](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/de-de/products/keyboards/natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000/b2m-00001) from MS.

However when using the ipad pro, I would like to use it with a virtual keyboard, so it's easily portable.

Comment: Have you done a search on "ergonomic keyboard" in the App Store?

Answer (score 1):

If by ergonomic keyboard you mean a *split* keyboard, you can do this natively on the iPad.

To do this:

- In the bottom right corner of the keyboard there is a key with a keyboard icon (with a black down arrow)
- Tap and hold that key
- A toggle for the split keyboard will pop up (or, if it's already split, a choice to unsplit the keyboard will appear instead)

**NOTE:** If the above steps don't work, first go to Settings > General > Keyboard and toggle the *Split Keyboard* option on.

Comment: This won't work on recent iPad Pros.  (Why?  Apple likes to maintain an aura of mystery,)